# How to change mouse cursor in jQuery resizable plugin?

Tags: jquery, cursor, resizable

When you use jQuery resizable plugin the mouse cursor style can be as "e-resize" (2 arrows in oposite directions). But, how can we change it? I've tried this:

```
$("#right-line").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("cursor", "crosshair");
});
```

But, it doesn't work, that is the cursor is still "e-resize".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To override the cursor of the Jquery resizable, you can just do :

```
$(selector).resizable({
        handles: "e",
        create: function( event, ui ) {
            // Prefers an another cursor with two arrows
            $(".ui-resizable-e").css("cursor","ew-resize");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The inline CSS is probably overridden by the jquery stylesheet. If you are loading it locally then you can edit `jquery.ui.resizable.css` or if you're using more UI widgets then the main `jquery-ui.css` and edit the `cursor` property.

The element you want to edit is `.ui-resizable-se` which is line 202 of `jquery-ui.css`

Comment: I've already figured out I could change the original .css file, but is it possible to do that in another way?

Comment: The problem is that I've made my own outer black div around the main rectangle. That outer black div is like a border and has 8 small squares in top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right corners and top-center, bottom-center, left-center and right-center locations, which I want to use as my own handles. It means I don't want to allow "e-resize" cursor along the whole border of container, but only on my own squares.